# Multiple Cloud Firestore for single project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a project with 2 schemes, one for development and other for production. I am also using firebase, hence I created 2 projects and injected two google plists under different names in the project. I also need to access google cloud platform. I cannot change/modify cloud functions without affecting my production application. Is there a way where I can have two Firestore for single project so that editing/ changing functions in on won't affect other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have multiple Firestore instances per project.

It's not entirely clear to me what the problem is with your use of Cloud Functions, but the functions running in each projects should automatically use the Firestore instance for the project that they've been deployed to.  If you need to access a different Firestore instance, then you will need to deploy some configuration for your functions so they can initialize an instance of the Cloud SDK that you're using to read and write Firestore

Comment: I have some notification methods in each function. So, whenever I edit the cloud function that deals with those methods, the live app is getting affected.

Comment: You said you have two projects - one for development and one for production.  You should only be deploying your changed functions to dev if you don't want them to affect the live app.

Comment: Yes. But both projects are under same Firebase project as 2 applications with different google info.plists. So the main firebase project has only one Cloud Firestore. So, whenever I do any backend related edits, both of them are affected.

Comment: Then you should move one app to the other project where it is more closely matched to the data it's using.

Comment: Yeah.. That is the only way. I was wondering if there is any way to set different Firestore environment as well like we do in Xcode. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Google launched the possibility of as many firestores for the same project

After checking the comments and ideas at this post, here is my full solution:

To create a second, third firestore database, access Google Cloud, open Cloud Shell, select the project, running

*“gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]”*

and then run the command

*"gcloud alpha firestore databases create --database=NAME - -location=LOCATION --type=firestore-native --delete-protection"*

Then navigate to the firestore session as shown in the image below

[image: print google cloud]

I created the following code that is working for me to use more than one firestore database.

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
// credencial export at https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/((YOUR_PROJECT_ID))/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk?hl=pt-br 
//and click the button to create a new pair of private key

const config = {
    credential: cert(serviceAccount)
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
const dbProduction = getFirestore(firebaseApp) //with no parameter, using default database
const dbDevelop = getFirestore(firebaseApp, "develop-database") //with name database as second parameter
const dbHomolog = getFirestore(firebaseApp, "homologation-database") //with name database as second parameter

//fast use to teste
dbProduction.collection("NAME_COLLECTION").add({test: true}) //.then()...
dbDevelop.collection("NAME_COLLECTION").add({test: true}) //.then()...
dbHomolog.collection("NAME_COLLECTION").add({test: true}) //.then()...
```

Comment: But in the client SDK, it's still not available

Comment: Now is possible

Answer (score 0):

Now is also possible user multiple databases firestore, using client SDK.

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot, getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-firestore.js";



const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXXX"
};
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

if(window.otherDb){ //user here the name of other database
  var db = getFirestore(firebase, window.otherDb);
}else{
  var db = getFirestore(firebase);
}


const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```